# User rails console to login as a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the rails console to and app.get to try to track down a bug that only happens for a specific user.  Is there a way to issue a request as that user with apt.get?

Also, I don't have the user's password.

```
app.get '/account/billing'
```

Returns a 302 that is redirecting me to the login page. I do have a cookie from an actual request, so one idea I had was to try to stick that in the header so the request would look like it came from that user.

I'm using Rails 3.2.0 for this.

Comment: Do you have more information about the bug? Do you know what's happening generally? Also I'd recommend using a service like Rollbar (free tier) or Honeybadger if you don't have them already. They help you log exceptions in production then you'll get a stack trace to work on. Good luck!

Comment: if you the admin / developer for the software, how about create new user for test with same profile / role like the user that reported has problem

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error in the logs, so not much help.

Comment: Try impersonate that user. These gems could help you https://github.com/rcook/user_impersonate2
 https://github.com/ankane/pretender